# Displaying SQL result in JSON and parse data using Javascript. Seperate text from [{:,}]

Tags: php, sql, json

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=sample;host=localhost", "admin", "passwd");        
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM accounts WHERE account_id='1'");
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo "$json";
?>
```

Result is

```
[{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}]
```

Expecting Result Using javascript:

```
John Doe
```

Comment: I really don't get what you're asking. You got your JSON string, so all you need to do is print it somewhere to JavaScript?

Comment: @Qirel i want to remove all the data from jason string except John Doe. and display using javascript or any other way.

Comment: What do you mean "remove all data", there is no more data than those two. The rest is the keys of those elements. Since you're also just matching one account, you could probably use `->fetch()` instead of `->fetchAll()`, that would give you a single row, instead of an array of rows.

Comment: @Qirel Originally my SQL query was "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM accounts"So i used fetchAll(). for the sake of making my question's answer short i changed my query to id= 1 ; [{"first_name":"john","last_name":"doe"},{"first_name":"Jeen","last_name":"dra"},{"first_name":"Ad","last_name":"Does"},{"first_name":"Arin","last_name":"Gan"},{"first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Ford"},{"first_name":"Prince","last_name":"addar"},{"first_name":"Derek","last_name":"Frenzi"},{"first_name":"Jay","last_name":"dar"},{"first_name":"dam","last_name":"guly"},{"first_name":"nita","last_name":"Sa"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the json code from your comment, you can do something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"first_name":"john","last_name":"doe"},{"first_name":"Jeen","last_name":"dra"},{"first_name":"Ad","last_name":"Does"},{"first_name":"Arin","last_name":"Gan"},{"first_name":"Jason","last_name":"Ford"},{"first_name":"Prince","last_name":"addar"},{"first_name":"Derek","last_name":"Frenzi"},{"first_name":"Jay","last_name":"dar"},{"first_name":"dam","last_name":"guly"},{"first_name":"nita","last_name":"Sa"}]');

for (i=0 ; i<obj.length ; i++){
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += obj[i].first_name + " " + obj[i].last_name + "<br>" ;
}
```